# Horror Episode #3: Venusian Vacuum

Tags: knowledge

One day when walking home from school, a student found a glowing object on the ground. Attracted like a bird, she picked up the object, which seemed to look like a relic. She took the object home and showed it to her brother, who was an archaeology major.

The brother investigated glyphs that he found on the side of the relic. The glyphs were unlike anything he had ever seen, almost as if they came from an advanced alien civilization. However, he saw what to draw inferences from on the relic. He said this was a knowledgable translation.

"We need our jack-o-lanterns. The power of this can get any lantern from a touch."

The young girl, confused, told her brother she was feeling drowsy and going to sleep. The brother took a closer look at the jack-o-lantern part of the translation, and got some insane concerns about him and his sister. He ran to his sister's room only to see she had turned into a skeleton and soon after, he turned into a skeleton!

What did the relic say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the brief answer, but I'm low on time and don't have much to say really:

> 'Lantern' could mean 'light' or 'life', which are often metaphorically linked. Jack is also a common name for a person. This means that 'Jack' might translate to 'human' and 'lantern' translate to life. Hence, they need 'jack-o-lanterns'/human lives, and the relic can take/gather (similar to 'get') any 'lantern' (life) with a mere touch.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

Whatsoever or whosoever the relic belonged to was looking for jack-o-lanterns and its just that their's are real human skeletons/Skulls.

SO,

> "We need our jack-o-lanterns. The power of this can get any lantern from a touch."

This means:

> They need jack-o-lanterns,our skull.The power of the relic can get any lantern,skull,from a touch

Since,initially the girl and later her brother touched the relic they both turned into the jack-o-lantern(skeletons,and definitely with a skull)

Comment: Close, but no. Think about where the term "jack O lantern" comes from